# How do you run a terraform module based on a variable value?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to run a terraform module only when a variable has a specific value
eg i only want this module to run if a variable has the value "y". Is this possible?

```
    module "azure-resource-group" {
    source = "./modules/azure-resource-group"
    name = "rgtest"
    location = "west europe"
   }
```

Comment: You can maybe try using `for_each`, something like: `var.somevar == "y" ? [1] : [0]`. But I'm not sure if that will work as expected.

Comment: @MarkoE To use `for_each`, it would have to be: `for_each = var.somevar == "y" ? toset(["1"]) : []`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't clear enough and made an error. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `count`:

```
module "azure-resource-group" {

    count = var.myvar == "y" ? 1 : 0

    source = "./modules/azure-resource-group"
    name = "rgtest"
    location = "west europe"
}
```

But then, when you actually create the module, you have to refer to it using index. For example:

```
locals {
  id =  module.azure-resource-group[0].id
}
```

Comment: why do you need to refer to is using index?

Comment: @itye1970 Because `count` will create a list with one instance of `azure-resource-group"`.

Comment: ok sorry to ask as am still learning terraform, what does the locals code do and where does this go?

Comment: @itye1970 This is just an example. Please read TF docs on [locals](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/locals) or any other topic you don't know.